# Hashing sequences with constraints

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to modify the following code to find all 100-mers (chunk of 100 nucleotide) that allow a mismatch every third base (a nucleotide). Any logic on how to approach this would be appreciated. Thank you!

> ```
> # length of hash key
> kmerlen = 30
>
> # hash table for finding hits
> lookup = defaultdict(list)
>
> # store sequence hashes in hash table
> print("hashing seq1...")
> for i in xrange(len(seq1) - kmerlen + 1):
>     key = seq1[i:i+kmerlen]
>     lookup[key].append(i)
>
> # look up hashes in hash table
> print("hashing seq2...")
> hits = []
> for i in xrange(len(seq2) - kmerlen + 1):
>     key = seq2[i:i+kmerlen]
>
>     # store hits to hits list
>     for hit in lookup.get(key, []):
>         hits.append((i, hit))
>
> # hits should be a list of tuples
> # [(index1_in_seq2, index1_in_seq1),
> #  (index2_in_seq2, index2_in_seq1),
> #  ...]
> ```

Comment: What is this program? What's a "mer"? What's a "base"? Realize we have no idea what this assignment is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to add a `step` term to your slicing expressions:

```
kmerlen = 30
kmerstep = 1     # new variable

# ...
for i in xrange(len(seq1) - kmerlen + 1):
    key = seq1[i:i+kmerlen:kmerstep]    # add step to slice
    lookup[key].append(i)

# ...
for i in xrange(len(seq2) - kmerlen + 1):
    key = seq2[i:i+kmerlen:kmerstep]    # here too
```

This will work for your tasks 2-4, with adjusted step sizes. Task 5 is a bit trickier, as it needs two out of every three items to match. I suggest concatenating two slices for that:

```
key = seq1[i:i+kmerlen:3]+seq1[i+1:i+kmerlen:3]
```

The items are not in order, but if you slice the other sequence the same way, they should correspond exactly. You might need to adjust the loop `range` for `i` as well.